# How to tap on toppest annotation MKMapView iOS?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have two types of annotations. By the first kind i have a bigger view and the next kind with smaller view. I have set the biggest annotation to always on the top of smaller annotations using,

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
```

this method but when i select the bigger annotation, most of the time smaller annotation which is on the back of the bigger annotation got selected. How can i select the front most annotation. Please guide me. Thanks.